# Factory functions and subclasses

Tags: python

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, filename, x):
        self.x = x
        # initialize A from filename

    # rest of A's methods

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        super(B, self).__init__(filename, 10)

    # rest of B's methods
```

Both classes are passed the name of a file in their `__init__` methods. The file contents are then used to initialize some data in the objects.

To facilitate testing I'd like to be able to construct an `A` or `B` instance by passing it the data directly, rather than having the object read from a file. I thought that a pair of factory functions, each implemented using a `classmethod` might work, but I've been unable to get the versions in `B` to work at all. Here's what I have so far:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @classmethod
    def construct(cls, filename, x):
        a = cls(x)
        # initialize a from filename
        return a

    @classmethod
    def test_construct(cls, data, x):
        a = cls(x)
        # initialize a from data
        return a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__(10)

    @classmethod
    def construct(cls, filename):
        # should construct B from filename

    @classmethod
    def test_construct(cls, data):
        # should construct B from data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the class methods in B to call their superclass class methods, you just use `super()` as though you were calling an instance in a base class:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__(10)

    @classmethod
    def construct(cls, filename):
        # should construct B from filename
        return super(B, cls).construct(filename, 10)
```

**Edit**:
As you point out in your comment, there is then a problem because you've added an argument to the base class constructor. You should avoid making incompatible changes in method signatures between base and sub-classes: a `B` instance *is* an `A` instance so it should accept any method call you can make to the `A` instance.

One option:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x=10):
        # if you're paranoid insert `assert x==10` here
        super(B, self).__init__(x)

    @classmethod
    def construct(cls, filename):
        # should construct B from filename
        return super(B, cls).construct(filename, 10)
```

and now it works again, but you have to trust yourself not to pass 'x' to directly constructed instances of `B`. Probably better would be to lose the `x` entirely from `__init__` which it looks like you could do by making it a class attribute or by setting it separately after construction.

Comment: I don't think this works. When `A.construct` is called from `B.construct` in this way, `cls` is bound to `B`. In the first line of `A.construct` the statement `a = cls(x)` tries to make a `B`, not an `A`.

Comment: @stw, Fair point, I forgot about your `__init__` having an incompatible signature. I've extended my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

the data at `__init__`.

You can make that optional and use `filename` in your program and `data` in your test:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x, filename=None, data=None):
        if not any((filename, data)):
            raise TypeError('either filename or data needs to be provided')
        if all((filename, data)):
            raise TypeError("both filename and data can't be provided")

        self.x = x
        if filename:
            with open(filename, 'r') as f:
                data = f.read()     # just an example
```

**Edit:** Anyway if you want use special constructors method, this is how I would it:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, data, x):
        self.x = x
        self.data = data

    @classmethod
    def construct(cls, filename, x):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            data = f.read()
        return cls(data, x)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(B, self).__init__(data, 10)

    @classmethod
    def construct(cls, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            data = f.read()
        # modify data as you wish
        return cls(data)
```

Where you call `construct` in your program and `__init__` in your test.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I considered something like this, but it doesn't have the right semantics. Both `filename` and `data` are optional, so it looks like you should be able to make an `A` without providing either, or perhaps both! I wanted to make a clean separation between client code (which calls `construct`), and test code (which calls `test_construct`).

Comment: @stw: You just need to add a couple of check to prevent the user from an imporer use of your class (I've added them). I've also updated my answer using your `construct`.

Comment: Thanks - I like the idea of only having one factory function (using `__init__` for tests). In the original hierarchy the base class handles all of the initialization of the data. The subclass simply passes the `filename` on in its `__init__` method. Is it possible to have `B.construct` call `A.construct` (in a similar way that `B.__init__` calls `A.__init__`)?

Comment: @stw: The only way to make it work is using `A.contruct(filename, 10)`, because with `super(B, cls).construct(filename, 10)` you call `A.construct` but with `cls = B` so you are bounced back to `B.__init__`.  *(If you like it maybe you want to think about up-vote it?)*